# saving editable text rendered in webView

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios5, xcode4.3

In my iPad app, I have created a rich text editor i.e some rich text content in the webView editable through some formatting buttons like bold, italics etc. I want to save the changes made through the editor in to the HTML file so that the next time the file is rendered in the webView those changes are visible. Is there a way to do that? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. First you want to save your html file. And then you can just get the path for it and let the webview load the html from that location.

```
//Retrieve location of file
       NSString *myFile= [NSBundle pathForResource:@"myHtmlFile" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:nil]; 
//Load your locally stored html text
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:myFile]]];
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Retrieving is not a problem as I am able to display the html file. What I need to learn is a way to save the changes made through the editor into that HTML file i.e. if I have bolded some text text in the editor then corresponding bold tags should get saved with the text in the html file.